# Hammock string/rope tangled with lawn mower blade

Tags: lawnmower, john-deere

I accidentally ran over a hammock on the ground with my John Deere S100, and now the string is stuck in the blade.

I tried using scissors and bolt cutters, but I am only able to cut out the outer part of the strings that were stuck.

The inner part is very tight. Scissors are not an option because it is too weak, and bolt cutters are not flexible enough.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Can anyone help me? I don’t know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair (BTW) !

Comment: FYI the blade is removable.  If you did not know that, it's probably *super dull*.  Time to inspect, sharpen and/or replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the blade off of the mower. There should be a single bolt in the center. Should allow you to get to the string easier and clear it from the blade and the shaft.

Comment: Sometimes such a bolt has a reverse thread. Although [this site](https://lawnmowerguru.com/are-lawn-mower-blades-reverse-thread/) says John Deere mower blades are not reverse threaded.

Comment: They are not left-handed on my John Deere 100 series.

Comment: The concept of reverse threat is not in blades but in the nuts which are used to fasten the blade in the shaft in the anti-clockwise direction. Although [this site](https://greenryenthusiast.com/are-lawn-mower-blades-reverse-threaded/) says The concept of tightening the nuts in an anti-clockwise direction is called a reverse thread.